# Частица "не" и глагольная приставка "недо" - слитно/раздельно

Tags: частица-не

*Недоеден обед, не дочитана детская книжка.*

Как правильно пишется "недоеден" - слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 3):

Рассказывает Грамота.ру:

**[Вопрос № 251968](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=251968)**

> Объясните мне, пожалуйста, правописание приставки НЕДО с глаголами. И
> как различать написание приставки НЕДО и частицы НЕ с глаголами
> (например: *недописал* работу или *не дописал* работу)?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> *Не* пишется слитно в составе глагольной приставки *недо*-, означающей **неполноту, недостаточность по сравнению с нормой**. Без *не-* такой глагол не будет иметь смысла, например: *они хронически недоедают* (=
> 'едят недостаточно; плохо питаются'; невозможно раздельное написание,
> т. к. нельзя *хронически доедать*), *няня недосмотрела за ребенком* (=
> 'плохо присматривала, не уберегла от какой-либо неприятности'; не
> имеет смысла сочетание *досмотреть за ребенком*), ср. также: *А он
> шутил – недошутил, / Недораспробовал вино / И даже недопригубил* (В.
> Высоцкий. «Прерванный полет»).
>
> Но от глаголов с приставкой *недо-* следует отличать глаголы с
> приставкой *до-* и предшествующей частицей *не* (такие глаголы с
> частицей *не* **обозначают не доведенное до конца действие**),
> например: *мы не досмотрели до конца фильм* (=не смогли досмотреть);
> *наш сын часто не доедает свою порцию* (= не хочет, не может доесть). Ср. пример из той же песни В. Высоцкого «Прерванный полет»: *Но к ней
> в серебряном ландо / Он не добрался и не до... / Не добежал,
> бегун-беглец, / Не долетел, не доскакал...* (= не смог добраться, не
> смог добежать...).
>
> В приведенном Вами примере верно слитное написание *недописал* в
> значении 'написал меньше нужного' и раздельное написание в значении
> 'не смог (не захотел, не успел...) дописать'.

Так что возможны два варианта в зависимости от вкладываемого автором смысла.

В приведенном Вами примере верно слитное написание *недоеден* в значении 'съдена не вся порция' и раздельное написание в значении 'не смог (не захотел, не успел...) доесть обед'.

Comment: Речь о глаголе, а здесь - краткое  причастие.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае правильность написания зависит от контекста, но лучше выбрать одинаковую форму письма:

***Не доеден обед, не дочитана детская книжка.*** Действие не доведено до конца, прервано.

Answer (score 2):

> Как правильно пишется "недоеден" - слитно или раздельно?

Возможны оба написания — и раздельное и слитное.

В первом случае будет иметь место сочетание частицы *НЕ* с формой *доеден* (краткая форма страд. прич. *доеденный*), во втором случае используется краткая форма страд. прич. *недоеденный*.

Наличие обеих форм в русском языке подтверждают и примеры, приведённые в параллельных ответах в этой теме, и словари.

Из **"Грамматического словаря русского языка" А.А. Зализняка**:

> **доесть** св. *спряж. см.* заесть
>
> **недоесть** св. *спряж. см.* заесть
>
> **заесть** … *прич. страд.* заеденный

См. фото:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из **"Орфографического словаря русского языка" Б.З. Букчиной и др.**:

> **недоеденный**, *прич.; кр. ф.* недоеден…

См. фото:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что же до разбираемого примера, согласен с другими ответившими: лучше выбрать одинаковую форму письма. И если "не дочитана…" написано в задании раздельно, то и для "не/доеден" стоит использовать раздельное написание:

***Не доеден обед, не дочитана детская книжка.***

Comment: Ссылку на словарь Зализняка не вижу, пыталась найти онлайн- не нашла, а вот на Грамоте в словаре такого слова недоеден нет.http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lv=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9   В словаре Букчиной нет различения причастий и отглагольных прилагательных.

Comment: _Людмила: Ссылку на словарь Зализняка не вижу..._ === Приведённые мной фото не открываются?

Comment: _Людмила: В словаре Букчиной нет различения причастий и отглагольных прилагательных._  === ??? Из словаря (стр. 10): "Если образованное от страдательного причастия прошедшего времени совершенного вида прилагательное имеет краткие формы, которые пишутся так же, как краткие формы причастий (с одним **н**), **при причастии кроме пометы _прич._ даются также пометы _прил._ или также _в знач. прил._** <…>"

Answer (score 1):

*(Не)доеден обед, не дочитана детская книжка.*

```
  Как правильно пишется "недоеден" - слитно или раздельно?
```

Начнём с выяснения, НЕ здесь употреблено **с какой частью речи**. Это не глагол. Это **или причастие, или отглагольное прилагательное.**

Отглагольное прилагательное образуется только от глаголов **несовершенного вида**: кипяченое молоко от кипятить, жженая пробка от жечь. У нас от глагола доесть (а не **недоедать в значении "есть мало"**)- что **сделать? - сов. вид, следовательно, это причастие.** Есть ещё один способ проверить - подставить зависимое дополнение, если это возможно, то это причастие: *обед доеден кем-то / не доеден кем-то.* Подставилось легко - это причастие.

**Не с кратким причастием всегда пишется раздельно.**

Sharon Вам дала ещё одну подсказку: лучше выбрать одинаковую форму письма (конструкции здесь параллельны, вряд ли будут использованы разные части речи, это качество хорошей речи). Если второе - краткое причастие, то и первое будет оно же, оба пишутся раздельно.

Comment: **Людмила**, из Вашего ответа вроде бы следует, что _не/доеден_ **никогда** не может писаться слитно. Вы так действительно считаете?

Comment: Может, если это краткая ф. прилагательного недоеденный от глагола недоесть в знач. "съесть, но  мало, не весь кусок, только откусить от него", т.е. объеденный.(Недоесть встречается только у Даля как разговорное -  покидать часть пищи несъеденной, )Тогда у нас было бы недоеденный обед = объедки на столе. Но у нас-то именно в знач. "обед не доеден кем-то" = не съеден до конца по какой-то причине ребёнком, нам важно, что субъект не довёл действие до конца, а не внешний вид обеда. Это причастие, а страд. причастия прош. вр. образуются от переходных глаголов НСВ и СВ - от доесть, а не от недоедать

Comment: _Людмила: Может, если это **краткая ф. прилагательного** недоеденный от глагола недоесть..._ === Наверное, **краткая ф. причастия**?

Comment: Краткие причастия с частицей НЕ пишутся только раздельно, краткие прилагательные  - как в полной форме. Разве не так?

Comment: Наверное, так... Но в _недоеден_ нет НЕ. Есть приставка НЕДО.

Comment: Какая разница, это частица НЕ, которая входит в приставку, есть частица НЕ, которая является приставкой. Всё равно это орфограмма "Правописание частицы НЕ со всеми частями речи".   Есть не только узкое значение слова "частица", но и широкое.

Comment: _Людмила: Всё равно это орфограмма "Правописание частицы НЕ со всеми частями речи"._ === И как эта орфограмма рекомендует писать частицу НЕ с глаголами? Раздельно? Тогда почему же Вы причастие **недоеден** считаете нужным писать раздельно, а глагол  **недоесть** пишете слитно?

Comment: slava1947, я же объяснила, что недоесть как пара к недоедать существует только в разговорном варианте у Даля (покидать часть пищи несъеденной) - это или просторечие, или диалект, от него и прилагательное недоеденный, а вообще в языке нет видовой пары у недоедать, как нет от него и страдательного причастия, т.к. он непереходный.

Comment: Уф... Как ни стараюсь, не могу разобраться: существует ли, по Вашему мнению, **причастие** _недоеденный_ с краткой формой от него _недоеден_, или же нет?

Comment: причастие - нет

Comment: Людмила, ссылку на словари я поместил в своём ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Почему возможны обе формы (***недоеден обед и не доеден обед***)

***Недоесть*** – глагол совершенного вида, от него можно образовать причастие, в том числе краткую форму: ***недоеденный, недоеден.***

Это относится ко всем глаголам с приставкой НЕДО.

**Выбор делается по значению с учетом контекста:** недостаточное (неполное) действие иди действие, не доведенное до конца.

Примеры

: **Поля – недоработаны, Посевы – недосеяны,** Порядку нет следа! (Н. Некрасов).

К радости Лавра, взятая им из монастыря краюха **все еще недоедена.** [Евгений Водолазкин. Лавр (2012)]

Из словаря:

**НЕДОЕСТЬ**, св. Поесть недостаточно, не досыта. * Пригож и мил, кто недоест и недоспит до свадьбы (Грибоедов). Сама недоем, а кота накормлю. <Недоедать (см.). Недоедание, -я; ср. Хроническое н.

**НЕДОЕДАТЬ**, -аю, -аешь; нсв. 1. **к Недоесть.** 2. **Есть недостаточно, плохо питаться**. Н. в детстве. Во время войны многие недоедали.

Answer (score 0):

> [недочитанный](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lv=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9); кр. ф. -ан, -ана (от недочитать)

Вполне допускаю, что на столе стоял недоеденный обед и лежала недочитанная детская книжка. Обед не захотели доесть, книжку не захотели дочитать.

**Недоеден обед, недочитана детская книжка.**

Согласен, лучше выбрать одинаковую форму письма.

Другой вариант. Землетрясение. Все срочно покинули помещение. **Не доеден обед, не дочитана детская книжка.**

Comment: На форуме сейчас обсуждается даже не значение, а грамматика глагольной формы: прилагательное это или причастие? Недоесть - недоеденный (прич.) иди недоедать - недоеденный (прилаг.). Как Вы думаете?

Comment: Я не уверен, поэтому "не обгоняю" :-)

Comment: Точно не уверены? Тогда  можно я Вам немного подскажу. Глаголы недоесть и недоедать образуют видовую пару, то есть имеют одинаковый смысл, но разную завершенность действия. (Правда, у "недоедать" есть еще одно собственное значение, но пока не будем его учитывать). Из этого следует, что от глагола "недоесть" можно образовать причастие "недоеденный", то есть такое причастие по крайней мере существует. Будет ли оно переходить в прилагательное? Я не вижу для этого причин.